# How to replace many symbols with a single word in Lua?

Tags: lua, replace

I must replace all of these characters, "①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩", with "\item".

I have used this code:

```
    stra = string.gsub(text, "①", "\\item")
    strb = string.gsub(stra, "②", "\\item")
    strc = string.gsub(strb, "③", "\\item")
    strd = string.gsub(strc, "④", "\\item")
    stre = string.gsub(strd, "⑤", "\\item")
```

However, this is very verbose. Is there a simpler way to replace all of those items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
local symbols_trans = {
    ["\226\145\160"]--[[①]] = "\\item1",
    ["\226\145\161"]--[[②]] = "\\bananas",
    ["\226\145\162"]--[[③]] = "\\cactus",
    ["\226\145\163"]--[[④]] = "\\etc",
    ["\226\145\164"]--[[⑤]] = "\\item5",
    ["\226\145\165"]--[[⑥]] = "\\item6",
    ["\226\145\166"]--[[⑦]] = "\\item7",
    ["\226\145\167"]--[[⑧]] = "\\item8",
    ["\226\145\168"]--[[⑨]] = "\\item9",
    ["\226\145\169"]--[[⑩]] = "\\item10",
}

text = string.gsub(text, "(\266\145.)", symbol_trans)
```

Or if you want to replace them all with`"\\item"`:

```
text = string.gsub(text,
    "\266\145[\160-\169]",
    "\\item"
)
```

`[\160-\169]` is equivalent to `[\160\161\162\163\164\165\166\167\168\169]`.
See the [Lua manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1) for information on ranges and, in general, Lua patterns.

You could also be fancy:

```
text = string.gsub(text,
    "\266\145([\160-169])",
    function(c)
        return "\\item"..(string.byte(c)-160+1)
    end
)
```

This will turn `①` into `\item1`, `②` into `\item2`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Use a "set" as described in the tutorial: http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial

```
string.gsub(text, "[①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩]", "\\item")
```

Comment: It should be noted that Lua doesn't handle Unicode. Even if those are UTF-8 strings, Lua won't know that. It will look for each UTF-8 code unit as it is. The only reason the original code worked was because Lua was looking for the *sequence* of code units. What you posted above will look for each code unit in turn.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a simpler way to replace all of those items?

Not without a Lua pattern matching library that knows what UTF-8 is. Lua is not Unicode aware; it has no idea how to search for Unicode symbols.

If you're using some non-multibyte encoding, then what John suggested might work. But not if it's UTF-8.

For your specific case, you could always do this:

```
local symbolsToChange { "①", "②", ...}

for i, sym in ipairs(symbolsToChange) do
  string.gsub(text, sym, "\\item")
end
```